# Oscillation of Howland DC current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, oscillation

I am trying to build a DC voltage controlled current source based on two op-amps as in the following schematic.

The Spice simulation results are quite ok, but when I test the PCB with an oscilloscope, there is an unwanted oscillation at the output.

Note: DC input(+) at OPA 547.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try simulating it at 100 kHz or so?

Comment: I don't understand how a DC input at OPA547 could produce the output you're talking about.  Do you have a *different* scope reading showing an oscillation when the input is DC???

Answer (score 2):

You are using an [LM324 op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324-n.pdf?ts=1637148653431&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM324-N%253Fqgpn%253Dlm324-n) configured as a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 26. The GBWP of the LM324 is 1 MHz and this means that it will just about work with a gain of 26 at no higher than 38 kHz. Your signal input is 150 kHz so, at this frequency, you **WILL** get bad results.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, there is DC input(+) at OPA 547.

Comment: There was no misunderstanding until you commented.

Answer (score 1):

Spice models of opamps are crude approximations at best. They never contain all parasitics or accurately model the transfer characteristics. You have coupled two opamps in a feedback loop, which can be unstable quite easily. Look at the datasheet what the transfer characteristic of your opamps is, calculate from there what your phase margin is. Then tweak your circuit until your phase margin is at least 45°, as you need some head room for the variation in opamps due to production and temperature.